# DataTables - TypeError: this.s.subButton[c] - Excel export

Tags: jquery, firefox, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm having problems with the datatables excel export function.

The problem only occured in Firefox 45.0.2.
Currently I'm using datatables 1.10.10 and Buttons 1.1.0 (buttons.colVis).

In chrome, edge and opera everything works as expected.

Already tried the newest dataTables files and it seems as if the problem is also part of the 1.10.11 release.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                //INITILIAZE THE DATA TOGGLES
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                //BEGIN - Show loading Modal and disable closing
                $('#loadingModal').modal("show");
                $('#loadingModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });

                var table = $('#dTable').DataTable({
                    "ajax": '../php/ajax/views/relations/getAllRelations.php',
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    stateSave: true,
                    iDisplayLength: 25,
                    "orderClasses": false,
                    buttons: [
                        {extend: 'copy', className: 'btn btn-raised btn-default'},
                        /* BUG IN FIREFOX */
                        {extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-raised btn-default'},
                        {extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-raised btn-default'},
                        {extend: 'colvis', text: 'Ansicht', className: 'btn btn-raised btn-default', columns: ':gt(0)'}
                    ],
                    "language": {
                        "url": "../php/ajax/views/relations/GermanDataTables.json",
                        buttons: {
                            copyTitle: 'Daten kopiert',
                            copy: 'Kopieren',
                            //excel: 'Excel',
                            print: 'Drucken'
                        }
                    },
                    //BEGIN - Hide column "ID"
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": [0],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "initComplete": function () {
                        //BEGIN - Close loading Modal and enable closing
                        $('#loadingModal').unbind();
                        $('#loadingModal').modal("hide");
                        $('.buttons-colvis').on('click', function () {
                            $(".dt-button-collection").children().removeClass('dt-button').addClass('btn btn-raised colvisstyle');

                            $('.dt-button-collection').children('a').each(function () {
                                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                                    $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
                                }
                                else {
                                    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
                                }

                                $(this).on('click', function () {
                                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                                        $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                        switch (data[7]) {
                            case 1:
                                $(row).css('background-color', '#F44336');
                                $(row).css('color', '#FFFFFF');
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#dTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    var param = parseInt(table.cell('.selected', 0).data()) * 9452;
                    window.location.href = "editRelation.php?relation=" + param;
                });
            });
```

Here is the firefox console output:

```
TypeError: this.s.subButtons[c] is undefined
._buildButtons()
 datatables.min.js:216
._buildButtons()
 datatables.min.js:215
._buildButtons()
 datatables.min.js:216
._constructor()
 datatables.min.js:214
l()
 datatables.min.js:209
.fnInit()
 datatables.min.js:238
nb()
 datatables.min.js:69
ia()
 datatables.min.js:85
m/</<.success()
 datatables.min.js:128
m.Callbacks/j()
 jquery.min.js:2
m.Callbacks/k.fireWith()
 jquery.min.js:2
x()
 jquery.min.js:4
.send/b()
 jquery.min.js:4
```

If I comment out this line {extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-raised btn-default'} everything works in Firefox.
If I set this line firefox is stuck on loading the content.

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Comment: Why do you believe the problem is dataTables, when the error only occurs with a specific version of FireFox? Tested https://jsfiddle.net/zm825k01/2/ with FF 39.0, no problem.  A quick google search on 45.0.2 reveals a lot of people suddenly facing TypeErrors, "x is undefined" and so on with code that always have worked in other versions and browsers, so I believe the problem is FF and a unresolveable issue seem from a dataTables point of view (a hack for a specific FF version would be pointless) ...A reference to line numbers from the none-minified script versions would be helpful ...

Comment: tested firefox 46.0 and the error is still part of this release. I'll check the none-minified script and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks I found out that I must include the jszip library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/DataTable/jszip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for the help.